# What does array[i].count return in javascript? What is its equivalent in actionscript? Or how can it be implemented in Actionscript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript, multidimensional-array

What does

```
array[i].count
```

return in javascript? What is its equivalent in actionscript? Or how can it be implemented in actionscript?

Comment: very likely to be closed, as you have not provided anyone with any clue on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `i` is a number this will simply get the ith element from the object and then attempt to resolve the property `count` on that object.

```
var elem = array[i];
elem.count;
```

The `count` lookup is no different here than `count` lookup on any other object